# Put items with date = today first in collection (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have a collection of all events `$events = App\Event::orderByDesc('start_date')->get()`. Now I want to put the events of today first, while keeping the order of the other events. I think I should use `reject()` and `prepend()`, but I am not able to combine both..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try make use of the [partition](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-partition) method of collection like so:

```
// Create 2 collections, One for today's event and another for the other days
list($todays, $otherDays) = App\Event::orderByDesc('start_date')->get()->partition(function($event){
  // NOTE: change the date comparison as necessary such as date format. I assume you use carbon here
  return $event->start_date === \Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString();
}

$events = $todays->merge($otherDays);
```

As an alternative, I found this [post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/move-collection-item-to-end-of-collections?page=1) that makes use of the reject method. For your case the code will be something like:

```
$filterFunc = function($event){
  return $event->start_date === \Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString();
}

$collection = App\Event::orderByDesc('start_date')->get();

$events = $collection->filter($filterFunc)->merge($collection->reject($filterFunc));
```